# Finding groups from presentations

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-presentation

I am trying to solve the following problem: Find all groups with two generators $a$ and $b$ in which $a^4 = 1, b^2 = a^2, $ and $bab^{-1} = a^{-1}.$

I know that this is a presentation of the quaternion group, and am confused about whether this presentation can be a part of the presentation of some other group. Is it possible that this can be part of the presentation of another group? How would I construct another group?

Comment: Yes, I would. That would give me the Klein-4 group, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $Q_8 = \langle\, a, b \mid a^4 = 1,\ b^2 = a^2,\ bab^{-1} = a^{-1} \,\rangle$. For every group $G$ with generators satisfying the relations, there is a surjection from $Q_8$ to $G$ by [the von Dyck theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/vonDycksTheorem.html) or by the universal property of group presentation. (See [Aschbacher 2000, [(28.6)](https://books.google.com/books?id=BprbtnlI6HEC&pg=PA140)] or [Grillet 2007, [Theorem 7.2](https://books.google.com/books?id=LJtyhu8-xYwC&pg=PA33)].) Thus $G$ is isomorphic to one of

- trivial group — $1$,
- group of order $2$ — $C_2$,
- Klein four group — $V_4$, or
- the whole group — $Q_8$.